# Sequelize Insert Many to Many

Tags: sequelize.js

What is the right way to insert in a many-to-many relation while setting references all in one shot? I don't want to xreate objects first and then set the references in another step.

```
Product.belongsToMany(models.Aisle, { through: 'AisleProduct' }); 
Aisle.belongsToMany(models.Product, { through: 'AisleProduct'});

var product = models.Product
            .build({
                AisleId:[1,2]  // This does NOT work!
            });
product.save();
```

This does not work either

```
var product = models.Product.build({});
product.setAisles(AisleId:[1,2]);
product.save();
```

as `setAisles` tries to save the object which does not have an id yet and throws an exception

Comment: you got an answer to this. please update. It would of a great help.

Comment: The correct solution is to use a transaction, set all attributes of all tabels involved and commit...

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Aisles first. Sequelize doesn't support creating the associated object during the build phase of the relative.

Your code should look something like this :

```
models.Aisle.create({}).then(function(aisle1) {
  models.Aisle.create({}).then(function(aisle2) {

    models.Product.create({}).then(function(product) {
      product.setAisles([aisle1, aisle2]);
    });

  });
});
```

You can create your own `beforeCreate` [hook](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/hooks/#beforecreatename-fn) that can create the Aisles via the options before you save the Product.

`BelongsToMany` relation adds another table to your database `productAisles`, which needs to be populated to save the relation, so practically you will not save any queries if you first build the Aisles and then add them to your Product.

Comment: This is taking 4 db access. 3 creates and one setAisles(). Is that possible to do all of the above it in 3 db accesses?

Comment: No ... According to the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations), sequelize will create another table for the associations, so there will be another query. If you think about it, there is no way to create belongsToMany association without having an extra table, so you will need another query.

Comment: This is not a valid approach. imagine you get an HTML POST to create a new product that belongs to a couple of aisles, but some of those aisle `id`s are just invalid random numbers. With your approach the aisle will be created BUT will get an Exception when it tries to `setAisles`, so you end up with a product that doesn't belong to any aisles.

Comment: If you don't like this approach you can find another library that suits your needs :) Anyway Sequelize supports transactions so you can bound any queries and if one of it fails it will revert the ones that haven't

Comment: has this changed or gotten better?